# 404 NOT FOUND when I try to access my project's index.php

Tags: apache2

I have a 404 NOT FOUND when I try to access my project's index.php with LAMP installed. I thought of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` to make sure that the rewrite module is enabled. but I face the same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem solved. I placed my project folder here: `/var/www/html/` and then reloaded `localhost/project_name/index.php`.